Implementing the reflection in Grover's algorithm with $\{\mathtt{CNOT}, H, X\}$
Suppose we have a boolean function $f : \{0, \cdots, N - 1\} \to \{0, 1\}$ and want to determine $x$ such that $f(x) = 1$ given a reduced quantum oracle $V_f$ defined by
$$
V_f | x\rangle := (-1)^{f(x)} |x\rangle \quad \forall x \in \\{0, \cdots, N-1\\}
$$
Furthermore, suppose the number of $x$ such that $f(x) = 1$ is $S \ll N$. The description I have of Grover's search algorithm is given by


Prepare the system in the Fourier basis state $e_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt N} \sum^{N-1}_{x = 0} |x\rangle$
Apply the reduced oracle $V_f$
Apply the gate $W := 2 |e_0\rangle \langle e_0 | - I$
Repeat steps 2 and 3 $K$ times, where $K$ is the closest integer to $\frac \pi 4 \sqrt{\frac N S} - \frac 1 2$.
Measure the system in the computational basis


I am trying to understand how to implement the gate $W$ with gates from the set $\{\mathtt{CNOT}, X, H\}$ in the case where $N = 4$. In this case, $|e_0\rangle$ is $|+\rangle \otimes |+\rangle$. I have a hint that says to consider the action of $(I \otimes H)(\mathtt{CNOT})(I \otimes H)$ but after trying this on $|0\rangle \otimes |0\rangle$ and trying to put in $I \otimes X$ or $X \otimes X$ in various places, I still can't get anywhere. My questions are then:

How can $W$ be found this way?
When answering questions related to finding the composition of gates from a gate set that implement a specific gate, it feels a lot like I'm reaching around in the dark and just performing blind symbolic manipulation until spotting a combination that works. For finding $W$ in particular, am I missing a more conceptual understanding that would at least give me a rough idea on how to start, e.g. related to the Bloch sphere?


First, consider that to prepare the equal superposition state $|s\rangle$ (which you call $e_0$) from the all zero state $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ all you need to do is apply a Hadamard gate to each of the $n$ qubits:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
|s\rangle &= H^{\otimes n} |0\rangle^{\otimes n} 
\\
\\
|s\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{x = 0}^{N -1} |x\rangle,
\end{aligned}
$$
with $N = 2^n$.
Since, the Grover diffusion operator $U_s$ (which you call $W$) is given by this expression:
$$ U_s = 2 |s\rangle \langle s| - I, $$
you can replace $|s\rangle$ (and $\langle s|$) resulting in:
$$ U_s = 2 \, H |0\rangle  \langle 0| H - I. $$
Here I have omitted the $^{\otimes n}$ in both the Hadamard gates and all-zero states to make the expression cleaner, but these are still for a system of $n$ qubits (same for the identity operator $I$).
Notice that since $H H = I$, we can sandwich the identity in the expression above without changing the result:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
U_s &= 2 \, H |0\rangle  \langle 0| H - H \, I \, H
\\
\\
U_s &= H \left ( 2 |0\rangle  \langle 0| - I \right) H
\end{aligned}
$$
Next, consider the matrix representation of the expression in between the $H$ gates above:
\begin{aligned}
2 |0\rangle  \langle 0| - I = & \, \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
2 |0\rangle  \langle 0| - I = & \, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & -1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
2 |0\rangle  \langle 0| - I = -1 & \, \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{bmatrix} 
\\
\\
\end{aligned}
This last matrix corresponds to a gate that inverts the phase of the all-zeros state, and the pre-factor of $-1$ is simply associated with a global phase we can ignore. To construct this gate, you can first flip all bits with an $X$ gate, apply a multi-controlled $Z$ gate on all qubits $\text{MC}Z$, and then flip the bits back with another $X$:
$$ 2 |0\rangle  \langle 0| - I = X \, \text{MC}Z \, X .$$
Replacing in $U_s$ you get the following sequence of gates.
$$ U_s = H \, X \, \text{MC}Z \, X \, H, $$
where, again, all of these are being applied to all qubits.
You can construct the $\text{MC}Z$ gate with a $\text{MC}X$ where you apply $H$ gates before and after the target qubit (since $Z = \,H \,X \,H$). Here's a circuit diagram of how $U_s$ would look like for $4$ qubits:

Finally, if you really need to implement the $\text{MC}X$ gate out of just $\text{C}X$ gates, you can follow the techniques described in section 7 of the Elementary gates for quantum computation paper. But in the particular case of $N = 4$ (i.e., 2 qubits), the $\text{MC}X$ gate is just a $\text{C}X$ gate.
